# Parsing the GFP2Element in Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to use the example of DH for generating AES key in this site https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Diffie-Hellman

But I am changing it with XTR-DH and I want to print out the generator number and it can't appear because `.GetSubgroupGenerator()` using GFP2Element class

Here is code

```
int main()
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool aSRP;
    XTR_DH xtr(aSRP, 251, 224);
    SecByteBlock priv(xtr.PrivateKeyLength());
    SecByteBlock publ(xtr.PublicKeyLength());
    SecByteBlock secretKey(xtr.AgreedValueLength());
    xtr.GenerateKeyPair(aSRP, priv, publ);

    cout << "Prime: " << xtr.GetModulus() << endl;
    cout << "Generator" << xtr.GetSubgroupGenerator() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, what is the solution? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably show some code and state where your problem is. You might also be interested in [XTR-DH](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/XTR-DH) on the Crypto++ wiki. Finally, you will almost certainly want [Commit 44cd7eb1ed8460d4](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/44cd7eb1ed8460d4) It was a recent check-in, and will be available in Crypto++ 7.1.

Comment: @jww I have been post my code. Thanks before

Comment: Now related: [Key agreement with XTR-DH Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52587187/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GFP2Element` does not have an overloaded extraction operator. You simply print `c1` and `c2` members which are `Integer` types. (This is the same strategy for, say, elliptic curve field elements).

```cxx
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "xtrcrypt.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    AutoSeededRandomPool aSRP;
    XTR_DH xtr(aSRP, 251, 224);

    std::cout << "Prime: " << std::hex << xtr.GetModulus() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Generator" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  c1: " << std::hex << xtr.GetSubgroupGenerator().c1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  c2: " << std::hex << xtr.GetSubgroupGenerator().c2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
$ g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pthread test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
Prime: 607cd5cbdfa7ac6ed4fecaa83458fb7d9675a32f002a54380f22fd54d1b9c67h
Generator
  c1: 420c85a614a6f0426e6655a44fe6e1ea00ed27fbf1adbe23f4ad358ad837c9ah
  c2: 2ef44b40639a34fb0b4f9a5aab1d89bd0eca5c19c160e007daf1dd2bbe730eeh
```

Also see [XTR-DH](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/XTR-DH) on the Crypto++ wiki and the [`xtr.h`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/xtr_8h_source.html) header file.

---

Regarding:

```
XTR_DH xtr(aSRP, 251, 224);
```

`pbits=251` and `qbits=224` is slightly mismatched. For 80-bits of security it is recommended you use `pbits=170` and `qbits=160`. This equates to roughly a 1024-bit RSA modulus.

For 112-bits of security it is recommended you use `pbits=341` and `qbits=224-256`. This equates to roughly a 2048-bit RSA modulus.

For 128-bits of security it is recommended you use `pbits=512` and `qbits=256`. This equates to roughly a 3072-bit RSA modulus.

Also see [Security Level](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Security_Level) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: So the generator is two number or what else ? Because I create Bob side for agreement.